# Simple XML Framework - weird error

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jersey, simple-framework

Im using the Simple XML Framework within a Jersey REST Application and I am getting suddenly a lot of weird exceptions:

```
at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PrefixResolver.getPrefix(PrefixResolver.java:123)
at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PrefixResolver.resolvePrefix(PrefixResolver.java:183)
at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PrefixResolver.getPrefix(PrefixResolver.java:123)
at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PrefixResolver.resolvePrefix(PrefixResolver.java:183)
at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PrefixResolver.getPrefix(PrefixResolver.java:123)
```

(the error above is repeated a hundred times... and is continued by this below)

```
SEVERE: Exception mapper com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBExceptionMapper@da1be4   for Throwable javax.ejb.EJBException threw a RuntimeException when attempting to obtain the     response
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.StackOverflowError cannot be cast to    java.lang.Exception
    at javax.ejb.EJBException.getCausedByException(EJBException.java:91)
    at  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBExceptionMapper.toResponse(EJBExceptionMapper.java:63)
    at  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBExceptionMapper.toResponse(EJBExceptionMapper.java:54)
    at  com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapException(ContainerResponse.java:452)
    at  com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException(ContainerRespo nse.java:400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1404)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This is the XML it tries to parse (but sometimes it works, sometimes not):

```
<shoppinglistItem>
   <id>0</id>
   <article>
      <id>17</id>
      <name>Brunch</name>
      <price>0.99</price>
      <description>Brunch Brotaufstrich...</description>
      <picture>...</picture>
      <ean>125</ean>
      <substances class="java.util.ArrayList"/>
      <comments class="java.util.ArrayList"/>
      <ratings class="java.util.ArrayList"/>
      <stores class="java.util.ArrayList"/>
   </article>
   <count>1</count>
</shoppinglistItem>
```

I would be glad if anyone could give me a hint! =/
Im really going crazy with this...

Comment: The root error is `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, which is due to infinite recursion, as evidenced by all the repeated lines with `getPrefix()` and `resolvePrefix()`.

Comment: thats correct - but why are they running in that recursion...?

Comment: Can you post the XML it's trying to parse? If it's more than about 50 lines, can you upload to pastebin (or similar site) and add a link to your post? I'm guessing it's a bug in SimpleXML triggered by some weird XML.

Comment: I added the XML, but I do not see anything strange...

Comment: I think you need to submit this on [SimpleXML Mailing List](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/simple-support). I strongly suspect it's a bug.

Comment: Im in contact with them already - will post the result here...

Comment: the mailing list ist not able to provide a solution, they do also not know what the problem is =/ argh...

Answer (score 0):

OK, the only solution I have until now ist to change the model -.-
(SimpleXML Mailing List also had no hint or solution...)

Comment: What kind of change did you make to the model? I'm running into this problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. The reason was that SimpleXML apparently has trouble serializing the `Exception` class. I don't have a fix for this yet, but I will try to report this as a bug with SimpleXML. This reproduces the exception:

```
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
    someClass.exception = new Exception();

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    new Persister().write(someClass, stringWriter); // <<< Bam!

    System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
  }  

  public static class SomeClass {
    private Exception exception;        
  }
}
```